# How to generate an id for an embeddable class?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

**One** Note : **Many** Files

How can I assign an id in File since I cannot annotate it with @Id while keeping it embeddable? Currently, id in File table is null.

**Note**

```
@Entity
public class Note {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @JsonProperty(value = "noteID", access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
          name = "FILE",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "NOTE_ID")
    )
    List<File> files;

}
```

**File**

```
@Embeddable
public class File {
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String contentType;

    private String uri;
}
```

Comment: Why do yo want it to have an id? How about just assigning one?

Comment: When i need to get /update/delete a specific file of a note. I also thought of manually assigning it, but that requires me to ensure unique ids to assign and lock the access. It will be cool if there is a better way

Comment: If they have Id's and you want to reference them by those, why should they be embeddable?

Comment: as per our requirement, file only exist within the note context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make it a proper entity. @Embeddable is useful for value objects, i.e. objects that are identified by their values. But since you need an `id` this is obviously not the case in your scenario.

Your reason

> as per our requirement, file only exist within the note context

for choosing an embeddable is not valid. While I have seen phrases like this all over the place on the internet, you can use `@Embeddable`s in what ever context you want. As `@Embeddable` your `File` instances are not bound more or less to your `Note` instances than as `@Entity`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Embeddable`only when you need different objects but single entity. i.e 2 different classes together making a single database table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the @CollectionId annotation in the org.hibernate.annotations package. Since you cannot make this an Entity as per your answers above, you can make use of the @CollectionId annotation. This annotation need 3 properties: the columns, the generator and a type for the primary key in your Collection Object. Below is an example to help you :-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collection;
 import java.util.Date;

 import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
 import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
 import javax.persistence.Embedded;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
 import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
 import javax.persistence.Lob;
 import javax.persistence.Table;
 import javax.persistence.Temporal;
 import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

 import org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionId;
 import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
 import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

 import javax.persistence.Column;
 import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;


 @Entity
 @Table(name="USER_DETAILS")
 public class UserDetails 
 {

   private int userId;

   private String  userName;
   private Date joinedDate;
   private String description;

   private Collection<Address> listOfAddresses=new ArrayList<Address>();
   @Id@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   public int getUserId() 
   {
    return userId;
   }
   public void setUserId(int userId) 
   {
    this.userId = userId;
   }
   public String getUserName() 
   {
    return userName;
   }
   public void setUserName(String userName) 
   {
    this.userName = userName;
   }
   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
   public Date getJoinedDate() 
   {
    return joinedDate;
   }
   public void setJoinedDate(Date joinedDate) 
   {
    this.joinedDate = joinedDate;
   }
   @Lob
   public String getDescription() 
   {
    return description;
   }
   public void setDescription(String description) 
   {
    this.description = description;
   }
   public String toString()
   {
      return "[ "+getUserId()+", "+getUserName()+", "+", "+getJoinedDate()+", "+getDescription()+" ]";
   }
   @ElementCollection  
   @JoinTable(name="User_Address", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="User_Id"))
   @GenericGenerator(name="increment-gen",strategy="increment")
   @CollectionId(columns= {@Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")}, generator="increment-gen", type=@Type(type="long"))
   public Collection<Address> getListOfAddresses() {
    return listOfAddresses;
   }
   public void setListOfAddresses(Collection<Address> listOfAddresses) {
    this.listOfAddresses = listOfAddresses;
   }
 }
```

See the getter of the Collection, I have put in the annotation @CollectionId and have also specified the @GenericGenerator which is from the same package and provides a strategy for generating the Primary Key in your collection. I have used the same Generator in my @CollectionId. 
Hope this helps.